# Как сократить код на java?

Tags: java, android

Как убрать онотипный код  подставлять только переменные ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] facultets = {"Строительный", "УПП"};
    private String[] kurs = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
    private String[] groups = {"СВ-31", "СА-31", "СП-31"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Меню 1
        ArrayAdapter<String> facultetsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, facultets);
        facultetsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner sp_facultets = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_facultets);
        sp_facultets.setAdapter(facultetsAdapter);
        // Меню 2
        ArrayAdapter<String> kursAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, kurs);
        kursAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner sp_kurs = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_kurs);
        sp_kurs.setAdapter(kursAdapter);
        // Меню 3
        ArrayAdapter<String> groupsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, groups);
        groupsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        Spinner sp_groups = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_groups);
        sp_groups.setAdapter(groupsAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: что такое sp_groups,sp_facultets,sp_kurs? Где их объявление?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это спинеры

Comment: а одного не достаточно будет?

Comment: а в чем проблема сделать один спиннер как писал выше и просто грузить данные из массивов? при том что массивы у вас все стринговые

Comment: посмотрите так же в сторону правил именования переменных - https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html потому что у вас нейминг не совсем корректный :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 private Spinner defineSpinner(String[] array, int spinnerResource) {
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);
   
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(spinnerResource);
     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
     return spinner;
 }
```

Вызов:

```
  sp_facultets = this.defineSpinner(facultets, R.id.sp_facultets);
  sp_kurs = this.defineSpinner(kurs, R.id.sp_kurs);
  sp_groups = this.defineSpinner(groups, R.id.sp_groups);
```